# docker error FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/images/search?term=node: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit, docker 1.6.1, user is in docker group.

After OS boot every docker command execution cause this error:

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/images/search?term=node: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
```

this problem can be fixed by execution this command:

```
service docker restart
```

but after reboot error appears again.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

set docker to start at boot
here are commands for centos6

sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add docker

sudo /sbin/chkconfig --list docker

sudo /sbin/chkconfig docker on

hope it helps

link to Ubuntu how to :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/58404/how-to-start-and-stop-a-service

Comment: Please read [code formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).